# PHP: curl_setopt_array gives notice "array to string conversion"

Tags: php, curl

`curl_setopt_array( $ch, $curl_opt );`

This code gives a Notice `Notice: Array to string conversion in ...`

This is what `$curl_opt` contains:

```
array (size=5)
  42 => boolean true
  19913 => boolean true
  10018 => string 'PHP RestClient/0.1.2' (length=20)
  10005 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'user:password' (length=13)
  10002 => string 'http://longurl.com/' (length=389)
```

`is_array($curl_opt)` returns `true`, so I don't really know what's causing the notice.

I think I'm just missing something *really* simple here but I just cannot, for the life of me, figure this one out.

It's just a notice and doesn't break anything but it just annoys me that I don't know what's causing it.

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$curl_opt` should be a **one-dimensional** array................................

The key `10005` is not that case, it should be

```
$curl_opt = array(
  //...
  CURLOPT_USERPWD => '[username]:[password]'
  //...
);
```

Comment: I did not know this. Thank you. This solves my problem. Will accept as answer as soon as it allows me to.