# notice Array to string conversion curl_setopt_array ( )

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to execute this curl as shown below. but when executing it gives me error as

```
( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\XXX\workerInsBusiness.php on line 75
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0017  269704  {main}( )   ..\workerInsBusiness.php:0
2   0.0073  285048  curl_setopt_array ( )   ..\workerInsBusiness.php:75
```

Complet Source

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$city_ref=$_POST['cityselect'];
$area_ref=$_POST['areaselect'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$region=$_POST['region'];
$dist=$_POST['dist'];
$pincode=$_POST['pin'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
$shopname=$_POST['shopname'];
$url=$_POST['url'];
$businessdetails=$_POST['busdetails'];
$score=$_POST['score'];
$file=$_FILES['img']["name"];
$verification=$_POST['verification'];

$dt = date("ydmhms");
if(!$file)
{
    $newfn="Noimage";
}
else
{
    $name=explode(".",$file);

    $newfn = 'kdial_'.$dt.".".$name[1];
}

if($_FILES["img"]["error"]>0)
{
    $_SESSION["E_MESSAGE"]="Problem while uploading file, Please try again";
    header("Location: home.php");
}
else
{
    if((($_FILES["img"]["type"]=="image/jpeg")||($_FILES["img"]["type"]=="image/png"))&&($_FILES["img"]["size"]<=3145728))
    {//&&($_FILES["UFILE"]["size"]>50000)){
    //echo "File is ready to upload";
        if(file_exists("uploads/".$_FILES["img"]["name"]))
        {
            $_SESSION["E_MESSAGE"]="File already exist,  Please try again";
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/".$newfn); 

                $ch = curl_init();
                $curlConfig = array(
                    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://localhost:91/XXXX/allServices/insertBusiness.php",
                    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
                    'name' => $name,
                    'phone' => $phone,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'cityselect' => $city_ref,
                    'areaselect' => $area_ref,
                    'address' => $address,
                    'region' => $region,
                    'dist' => $dist,
                    'pin' => $pincode,
                    'category' => $category,
                    'shopname' => $shopname,
                    'url' => $url,
                    'busdetails' => $businessdetails,
                    'score' => $score,
                    'fn' => $newfn ,
                    'verification' => $verification,
                    )

                );
                curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                if (curl_errno($ch)) 
                {
                    // this would be your first hint that something went wrong
                    die('Couldn\'t send request: ' . curl_error($ch));
                } 
                curl_close($ch);
                //print_r("soham ".$result);
                $jsonobj = json_decode($result);
                print_r("json obj ".$jsonobj);
                exit();
            }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["ERROR"]="Invalid File";
        header("Location: home.php");
    }
}
```

file upload works properly.
What is problem with executing this curl i searched a lot i found some thing that says u must use http_build_query() but i dont know how to use this

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: curl\_setopt\_array gives notice "array to string conversion"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051930/php-curl-setopt-array-gives-notice-array-to-string-conversion)

Comment: are there any arrays inside the elements assigned to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` ?

Comment: i have updated my question their is no any array inside curlopt_postfields

Comment: its working, actually array was passing to $name variable because i used same variable name to create image name so i changed it and that worked now, thank you